# Title above Recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I want to put a textview above a recylerview.
My recylerview xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView   
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/contactListFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
    android:longClickable="true"
    android:paddingTop="60dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/listTitle"
    app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
    tools:context=".fragments.ContactFragment"
    tools:listitem="@layout/contact_item" />
```

tried to create a `xml` for the `textview` and set android:layout_above with the textviewId. I also tried changing the layout to vertical and set a `textview` then the `recyclerview` vertically but it only shows my text without the `recyclerview`.

I set the adapter in the opened fragment in the onCreateView.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);
    if (view instanceof RecyclerView) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view;
        if (mColumnCount <= 1) {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        } else {
            recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, mColumnCount));
        }
        recyclerView.setAdapter(new ContactViewAdapter(MainActivity.kontaktnotizListe,context));
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Do you want to ad the `textView` in each `RecyclerView` row item? If so, please share the layout of the row item..

Comment: No, just a text above the list.

Comment: Using the xml SlothCoding recommended i get the text but I get the error that no adapter is attached and it skips the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have TextView above RecylcerView you can do this in one XML like this. Insted of making your RecylcerView as root view just use LinearLayout as root

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/contactListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:paddingTop="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listTitle"
        app:layoutManager="LinearLayoutManager"
        tools:context=".fragments.ContactFragment"
        tools:listitem="@layout/contact_item" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this but then it will only show the text in the fragment not the list. I could use the textview as one item in the recyclerview but then i would have some coding to do . Is there another solution?

Comment: I am not sure this will show the only textview. Maybe your TextView had attribute layout_height = "match_parent", then it will do that probably. But with wrap_content it will wrap it and just show your test. I tested this XML in my AndroidStudio and it works fine. Don't do that hardcoding with one item as TextView. Try copying this inside your XML and check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (view instanceof RecyclerView)
```

was always false so I changed my onCreateView to

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, container, false);
    Context context = view.getContext();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.contactListFragment);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new ContactViewAdapter(MainActivity.kontaktnotizListe,context));


    return view;
}
```